# Mongoose - Can't do partial search even with a text index

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My express app has to do partial searches.

My subject model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var subjectschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Subject_Name: String,
    Subject_DOB: Date,
    Subject_Address: String,
    Subject_City: String,
    Subject_Prov: String,
    Subject_zip: String,
    Subject_Country: String
},{ strict: false });

subjectschema.index({ Subject_Name: "text" })

module.exports = mongoose.model("subject", subjectschema);
```

My Search route (POST):

```
router.post("/visit", middleware.isLoggedin, function(req,res){
    var text = req.body.user;
    subject.find({ $text:{$search: text}}).sort('Visit_date').exec(function(err,returnedsubjects){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(returnedsubjects);
            res.render("visit",{returnedsubjects: returnedsubjects});
        }
    });
});
```

Subject_Name in MongoDB is "Steven Smith"
* My search is case insensitive (Great!). Can search "Steven" or "steven".
* I can do partial full words. Can search "Steven" or "Smith"

But If I search "Steve" or "ste", I thought it would find the record. But it didn't.

How do I do that search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo text indexes do not support Partial or Fuzzy search.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Think of it as more of a keyword search. You could use regex which is not recommended since it does not use any indexes and will perform a full-scan on the collection.

ElasticSearch is a more optimized database for string search.

Or you could use Algolia https://www.algolia.com/

Comment: great. Thanks much!